# Fast comparison between two objects

Tags: javascript, object, compare

I need a fast way to compare between two objects.

I need the properties whose values changed, and also the properties that were added.
Some of the properties have values that are arrays or objects.

Example:

```
{a: 1, b: "hi",}
```

compared with

```
{b: "hmm", c: 3,}
```

result:

```
{b: "hmm", c: 3,}
```

Comment: give us more clarification about the criteria of comparison, based on what?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, [search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+diff+nested+objects+site:stackoverflow.com); if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)